# Obtain Kafka 'writeahead' messages with JVM consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, jvm, apache-kafka-streams

We have a streams app which makes use of exactly-once semantics, where one topic-partition has stalled.  We notice that offsets are going up in increments of two, and understand that the odd-numbered messages are part of the 2-phase commit of Kafka transactions.

We have written a `Consumer<Byte[], Byte[]>`(using kafka-clients 2.1.0)  to dump all of these messages to disk with `isolation.level = "read_uncommitted"`, but it is not fetching these odd-numbered messages.  Is there anything we can do to get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Control records](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#controlbatch) are not exposed to consumers.

To "see" them you need to use the DumpLogSegments tool:

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files /tmp/kafka-logs/mytopic-0/00000000000000000000.log
```

Control batches will appear like normal batches but they will have the `isControl` flag set to true.

> baseOffset: 1618 lastOffset: 1618 count: 1 baseSequence: 1
>   lastSequence: 1 producerId: 1000 producerEpoch: 0
>   partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: true isControl: false
>   position: 1778601 CreateTime: 1547217145114 isvalid: true size: 1097
>   magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE crc: 1680083731
>
> baseOffset: 1619 lastOffset: 1619 count: 1 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1
>   producerId: 1000 producerEpoch: 0 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0
>   isTransactional: true **isControl: true** position: 1779698 CreateTime:
>   1547217145210 isvalid: true size: 78 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE crc:
>   2028573478

You can also use the `--deep-iteration` flag to show single record metadata (or even `--print-data-log` to show actual record data). In that case, you can see if the control batch is a commit or revert:

> offset: 1618 position: 1778601 CreateTime: 1547217145114 isvalid: true
>   keysize: 3 valuesize: 1024 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId:
>   1000 producerEpoch: 0 sequence: 1 isTransactional: true headerKeys: []
>
> offset: 1619 position: 1779698 CreateTime: 1547217145210 isvalid: true
>   keysize: 4 valuesize: 6 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: 1000
>   producerEpoch: 0 sequence: -1 isTransactional: true headerKeys: []
>   endTxnMarker: COMMIT coordinatorEpoch: 0